# How to pass a Token to Request Headers in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, jqgrid

My project is in ASP Net Core with MVC.

I have a JQGrid in a view. It is working perfectly.
Now I have to authorize the Controller using an attribute to pass a JWT to the HttpContext Request Header.
In standard Ajax, I know that the headers attribute will take care of the task, but in JqGrid, how would one set the headers?

My code looks like this:

```
 $("#jqgrid").CreateGrid({
            url: "/api/fares/getfares",
            headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + '@Model.JWToken' },                
            colNames: ['Id', 'From', 'To', 'Date', 'Airline', 'FlightNo', 'Dep.Time', 'Arr.Time'],
            colModel: [..........],
            pager: '#pjqgrid',
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            loadonce: false,
            rows: 1,
            container: $('#div_jqgrid_container'),                
            loadingText: 'Loading..',
            noRecordText: 'No Records found',
        }, $("#jqgrid"));
```

The above code works, but not sending the Authorization header.
Some one please extend some help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, finally I got it. Add the option loadBeforeSend as a function in hte jqGrid code body like this. Now it works like a charm !

```
$("#jqgrid").CreateGrid({
        url: "/api/fares/getfares",
        // headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + '@Model.JWToken' },                
        loadBeforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + '@Model.JWToken' );
        },
        colNames: ['Id', 'From', 'To', 'Date', 'Airline', 'FlightNo', 'Dep.Time', 'Arr.Time'],
        colModel: [..........],
        pager: '#pjqgrid',
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadonce: false,
        rows: 1,
        container: $('#div_jqgrid_container'),                
        loadingText: 'Loading..',
        noRecordText: 'No Records found',
    }, $("#jqgrid"));
```

ps: If anybody would like the full code, please comment here and I shall post the complete jqGrid details.